# Python (Raspberry Pi 3) - Function call won't work inside if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I am having a bit of an odd problem. I am currently creating a system using a Raspberry Pi 3. The goal is to have a program that continues running indefinitely, looping through the same set of conditions over and over.
To do this, I am putting code from pyaudio into a function which I am later calling inside an if statement within a while loop.

Here is the code:

```
    print ("System ON")


def recordCASCON():
    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = 60
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "cascon.wav"

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("* recording")

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
        print(i)

    print("* done recording")

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()


while True:

    if GPIO.input(LedPin4) == GPIO.HIGH and GPIO.input(LedPin5) == GPIO.HIGH:
        print("initiating")
        recordCASCON()
```

I also want to note the following. The function works perfectly fine when called by itself. It also works fine when called within the while loop. Is ONLY when called within the if statement that I get the following in the shell:

```
System ON
initiating
* recording
```

As you can see from my code, the function runs for 60 seconds and prints the i index in the for loop. When the function works it runs a series of numbers for 60 seconds then I finally get the "done recording". In this case I could leave it for hours and is still stuck.
If I add a "break" at the end of the if statement all it does is the following:

```
System ON
initiating
* recording
0
```

It gets stock on 0 instead of recording.

Any suggestions or help? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're coding for a hardware like micro controller or so, have you checked whether your conditional statement won't mess you audio device? for example activation of condition happening at a time means the voice module have some pins messed up or so?

Comment: I am using an audio injector board that goes over all the raspberry pi 3 GPIOs. The audio injector board itself has it's own GPIO sets that I have connected to the system. So if I understand correctly, you think that the change in GPIO voltage could be causing the sound board to not function?

Comment: the fact that you have checked every possible scenarios without the if condition, points out that the problem could be a result of hardware problems, for example specific pin configuration as they may interfere with your audio module, or power problems.

Comment: that was beyond my reasoning, but I gotta say you might be absolutely right. I would be lying if I told you I have not had any problems with the hardware before during this project.

Comment: programming projects like yours that one have to co-design hardware and software can be tricky , but also fun and rewarding